# How to sort array of classes in C# by integer value?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a class `Player` that has fields `name` and `points`. i.e.

```
class Player { string name, int points }.
```

I have an array of these objects:

```
Program.playerList = new ArrayList();
```

I am displaying these objects in a Windows Forms program. I want to display them in order based on the number points a Player class has (the highest amount of points first). How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your question sort of reads as a set of requirements. Any code to show? What research have you done? These things will help us help you.  Good luck!   _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an `ArrayList`.
First, think if you really need it.
You are going to store `Player` objects there, so, it would be better if it was strongly-typed array `Player[]` or `List<Player>`.
However, if you for some reasons need an `ArrayList`, you will need to implement `IComparer`.

```
public class PlayersByPointsComparer : IComparer
{
    private readonly IComparer _baseComparer;

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        return ((Player)x).Points - ((Player)y).Points;
    }
}

// ...

Program.playerList.Sort(new PlayersByPointsComparer());
```

However, it there will be objects of non-`Player` type it will throw an exception. If it will not - then do you need an `ArrayList`?

If you replace in with an `Array`, you will be able to use `Array.Sort` or LINQ `OrderBy` method.

```
Array.Sort(Program.playerList, (a, b) => (a.points - b.points));
// or
Program.playerList = Program.playerList.OrderBy(x => x.Points).ToArray();
```

That's how you would sort it if you had a `List`.

```
Program.playerList.Sort(new PlayersByPointsComparer());
// or
Program.playerList.Sort((a, b) => (a.Points - b.Points));
// or
Program.OrderBy(a => a.Points).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, your right, I don't really need ArrayList. I am quite new to programming so still learning. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Please use generic collection `Type<Player>`, it has some advantages in compare with `ArrayList`. One is type checks of array items, second is possibility of using `Linq`.

You can use then

```
Program.playerList = Program.playerList.OrderBy(p => p.points).ToList()
```

or (without Linq)

```
Program.playerList.Sort((a, b) => a.points.CompareTo(b.points));
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be your Player class :

```
class Player : IComparable<Player>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Player other)
    {
        // Alphabetic sort if points are equal. [A to Z]
        if (this.Points == other.Points)
        {
            return this.Name.CompareTo(other.Name);
        }
        // Default to points sort. [High to low]
        return other.Points.CompareTo(this.Points);
    }
}
```

And to test it:

```
        List<Player> list = new List<Player>();
        list.Add(new Player() { Name = "Player1", Points = 50 });
        list.Add(new Player() { Name = "Player2", Points = 60 });
        list.Add(new Player() { Name = "Player3", Points = 30 });
        list.Add(new Player() { Name = "Player4", Points = 80 });
        list.Add(new Player() { Name = "Player5", Points = 70 });

        list.Sort();

        foreach (var element in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(element.Name);
        }
```

Here is the result:

[image]